# Do the two phrase 'none other than' and 'no other than' mean the same?

Tags: phrase-meaning, phrase-usage

In this following context, is the phrase "no other (cause) than" another form of "none other than"?

Do they mean the same thing?

Should I use these two interchangeably?

Could I do as: 'It can have nothing other than....' like changing of the phrase as: 'no other one than' > 'none other than'?

Context:

> This differencecannot be without reason, as it can be noticed at any
> time, and in any being.It can have **no other** cause **than** the pre-natal
> kamma-process.

Source: P. 40
"The Fundamentals of Buddhism" by Nyanatiloka Mahathera

Comment: "None other than" *tends* to be used for people, while "no other than" *tends* to be used for things, although it's more idiom than grammar.

Answer (score 0):

"*None other than [person]*" is an idiomatic phrase with a specific meaning. It is used to express surprise that the person has appeared in the context.

For example:

> You'll never believe who I saw in the supermarket! It was none other than multiple Grammy award-winning singer *Beyonce*!

According to Collins dictionary, you may also use "*no other than*" like this and it can be used for an inanimate object, but personally I've only ever heard it said about people.

This is entirely different to saying something like "*there was **no other** person there **than** me*". That is just said to highlight that you were alone, and you could just as easily say that about an object.